# Excel: Return position relative to name

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to return the position of a value relative to another column.

```
 Name   | Position
 Item A |     1
 Item B |     1
 Item C |     1
 Item A |     2
 Item A |     3
```

It's almost like a countif, but I dont want all Item A positions to have 3.
It seems simple enough, but I've been struggling to figure it out and haven't found anything in searches.

Comment: You mean you want something like what instance of the Name you are on?

Comment: I'm not certain I understand what you mean, but I want my count to see where Item A is in the list of Item As not the overall list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `B2` Enter

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)
```

Then drag down, it will count how many times the Name to the left has appeared above that instance of the name.

[image]

Comment: +1. @Piercy: notice that it's the locking of the cell that makes `COUNTIF()` work here!

Comment: Thank you for the help.  That was much faster than I thought it would be.